# Converting PyTorch into Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

How can I convert the next code into TensorFlow?

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from xy_dataset import XYDataset

TASK = 'road_following'

CATEGORIES = ['apex']

DATASETS = ['A', 'B']

TRANSFORMS = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ColorJitter(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2),
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

datasets = {}
for name in DATASETS:
    datasets[name] = XYDataset(TASK + '_' + name, CATEGORIES, TRANSFORMS, random_hflip=True)
```

I tried to change the transformers into some layers and nodes of Keras TensorFlow but it didn't work out as i expected in the first place

Comment: Try replacing torchvision with https://albumentations.ai/, it works in the same way in both pytorch and tensorflow.

Comment: It's a school assignment, it has to be the Keras Tensorflow framework

Comment: If possible, use [keras-cv](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/blob/master/keras_cv/layers/preprocessing/random_color_jitter.py). you can find many augmentation techniques.